# Add column to "Sales Order" history content in customer account

Tags: sales, history, order-history

**Hello Magento's,**

How we can add **column** to **Sales order history** content into **customer** account.

[image]

can anyone help me please?

Comment: what will be the content for that column ? Please see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to copy:

> magento2Root/vendor/magento/module-sales/view/frontend/templates/order/history.phtml

to

> app/design/frontend/{Package}/{theme}/Magento_Sales/templates/order/history.phtml

You can add custom column at above file where needed.

Comment: no the trick is without use history.phtml (no modification, no add, no override), i am looking for a solution with sales_order_history.xml and other configuration also needed.

Comment: you want to add column with xml ?

Comment: <referenceBlock name="extra.column.header" template="MageTun_Solution::history.phtml">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">MageTun_Solution::column.phtml</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>, i nedd to add a custom module and i use my owner template column.phtml   but this it's not working.

Comment: did you find any alternative ?